# If a $\sum a_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, does it converge absolutely and uniformly for $[-R+\epsilon, R-\epsilon]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If a $\sum a_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, does it converge absolutely and uniformly on $[-R+\epsilon, R-\epsilon]$

I can see that is converges absolutely, by definition of the radius of convergence, but I don't know how to show that the power series also converges uniformly on this interval, or to the contrary.

My reasoning is that since $R$ is the radius of convergence, then the series converges absolutely for $|x|<R$ and all the $x$ in that interval satisfy that condition. My definitions could be wrong though.

Comment: How do you show it converges absolutely, exactly?

Comment: My reasoning is that since $R$ is the radius of convergence, then the series converges absolutely for $|x|<R$ and all the $x$ in that interval satisfy that condition. My definitions could be wrong though.

Comment: But *why* would this be so?

Comment: By the comparison test, I think?

Comment: Show in detail how you do this.

Comment: I am actually not too sure

Comment: The reason Did is insisting on you giving the proof is that (a slight modification of) it will also yield uniform convergence. Keyword: Weierstrass M-test.